# Contagem de letras em um string

Tags: python-3.x

Preciso fazer um programa em Python que receba um string e retorne a soma das letras desse string em uma lista de tuplas, da seguinte maneira:
Exemplo:

banana -----> `[('b', 1), ('a', 3), ('n', 2)]`

Meu programa está assim:

```
for n in txt:
      c =  txt.count(n)
      if n != ' ':
          if n not in lista_txt:
              tupla = n, c
      lista_txt.append(tupla)
```

Porém ele retorna a soma de cada letra mais de uma vez:

```
[('b', 1), ('a', 3), ('n', 2), ('a', 3), ('n', 2), ('a', 3)]
```

Como posso resolver isso?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você está verificando apenas se `n` está na sua lista de tuplas, quando era para você estar verificando se a tupla `(n, c)` existe na sua lista

Outro detalhe é que você está adicionando a tupla na sua lista mesmo quando ela não passa pelas condições `!= ' '` e `(n, c) not in lista_txt`, você precisa indentar esse seu `append` para ele ficar dentro do `if`, dessa forma:

```
for n in txt:
    c =  txt.count(n)
    if n != ' ' and (n, c) not in lista_txt:
        tupla = n, c
        lista_txt.append(tupla)
```

Veja o código funcionando [aqui](http://www.pythontutor.com/live.html#code=txt%20%3D%20'banana'%0Alista_txt%20%3D%20%5B%5D%0A%0Afor%20n%20in%20txt%3A%0A%20%20%20%20c%20%3D%20%20txt.count%28n%29%0A%20%20%20%20if%20n%20!%3D%20'%20'%20and%20%28n,%20c%29%20not%20in%20lista_txt%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20tupla%20%3D%20n,%20c%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20lista_txt.append%28tupla%29&cumulative=false&curInstr=27&heapPrimitives=nevernest&mode=display&origin=opt-live.js&py=3&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&textReferences=false)

Answer (score 4):

Ainda que não respondendo diretamente à sua questão acho interessante mencionar que você consegue chegar ao seu objetivo de uma forma muito direta usando funções e estruturas já existentes no python.

Para tal basta servir-se de `Counter` para gerar um dicionário com as contagens, e da função `items` obter as contagens como uma lista de tuplas:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> texto = "banana"
>>> list(Counter(texto).items())
[('b', 1), ('a', 3), ('n', 2)]
```

[Veja a funcionar no Ideone](https://ideone.com/eaTLcX)

Como aparte, para além de ser mais direto é também mais efeciente pois a sua solução tem complexidade O(n²), ou seja quadrática, ao passo que com `Counter` a solução fica em O(n), linear.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode também usar um dicionário e ir setando as chaves e os valores, a medida que vai contando as vezes em que a letra contida na palavra se repete na sequência:

```
txt = 'banana'
dict = {}

for n in txt:
    c = txt.count(n)
    if not (n,c) in dict:
        dict.__setitem__(n,c)
print(dict)
```